# How to test function in PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have function in `PL/SQL Oracle` and right now I want to test does my function return correct value.

```
create or replace FUNCTION GETPROJECTSUPLIER(Project_id in int) 
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
     OPEN rc FOR
     SELECT * FROM projects_supliers WHERE ProjectID = Project_id;
     RETURN rc;
END GETPROJECTSUPLIER;
```

When I run it from `SQLDeveloper` I see that return value are correct but I need to pass `ProjectID` in function in order to get correct result.

Comment: What is the question here?  You have tested the function and it works, now what do you need to do?

Comment: FUnction needs `ProjectID` and I need to pass ProjectID in function in order to retrive Project By ID. I am asking how to pass Project ID in function. 
`CALL FunctionName(1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to test it would be:

```
select GETPROJECTSUPLIER(1) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try F5 below.

```
VARIABLE RC REFCURSOR
EXEC :RC := GETPROJECTSUPLIER(123)
PRINT RC
```